# Adapter for UI with combination of grid, linear layout and card in a single screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, android-studio-3.0

[UI skelton of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAsM4.png)

I'm using retrofit and Picasso libraries for connectivity and image loading. I'd like to implement an adapter for the above UI, so that dynamic Views can be created and load the images to it accordingly .

I'm aware of the adapters for each of them individually. 
But, How to combine both of them into one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Staggered RecyclerView. can look at offical doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager).

```
  RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    // set a StaggeredGridLayoutManager with 3 number of columns and vertical orientation
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
    //  call the constructor of YourAdapter to send the reference and data to Adapter
    YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter );
```

see the [example](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/) for getting started